# Is this inappropriate to say to a boss?

Tags: communication, india

I am a site engineer. Once, my project manager called me and yelled at me because I was not around when a delivery arrived. I told my manager I was in the toilet at the time,  which is a true. Afterwards, the assistant of the project manager came to my work place and started teasing me with my immediate boss. They said that my boss had not taught me manners, because I told a project manager I was in the toilet.

My question is, is it really wrong to say what I did in that situation? If I didn't say that he would have assumed that I was roaming somewhere avoiding work.

Comment: (I appreciate English may not be your first language, which is perfectly OK) But could you try to clarify the sentence "you have not taught manus to your assistant he tells he was pissing, in front of a project manager.", as it's not clear what you are trying to say.

Comment: @Bilkokuya might it be "manners"?

Comment: i mean they were telling that infront of a person like project manager is wrong.since i told i was in toilet.

Comment: @vinayakumarJ I've done my best to edit this into clearer English, however - it is my best interpretation, and so if this does not reflect your intended meaning, please reject/rollback.

Comment: i only told him i was in toilet yesterday

Comment: I'm afraid this might be *very* localized. For example, in my country, saying "I took a piss" would be bad manners indeed (too much intimate detail), while "I was using the restroom" or even "I was using the toilet" is the polite way to put it. I have no idea about your region, culture and language of India, but it seems you might be the best person to answer your own question.

Comment: "in toliet" doesn't translate well to other cultures which don't see a "toilet" as a room, but as the item you sit upon.  Next time, try "in restroom" and odds are you won't get the teasing.  That said, it's not really appropriate to tease, but until companies don't contain people, some level of light teasing is going to happen from time-to-time.  If you can accept the teasing gracefully, it tends to lessen.  Fighting it tends to amplify it.  It's another way the world works in a wrong manner, those that express their bother tend to get more of it.

Comment: @EdwinBuck Unfortunately no one word works in every English speaking culture. If you used "restroom" in England you would probably get teased because people there consider that to be a silly euphemism, although they often use the word "bathroom" even if it doesn't contain a bathtub or shower.

Comment: I take the minor teasing as a good sign. You have been accepted into the circle a bit. If you were not accepted or they were going to fire you, then they certainly would not be visiting you and razzing you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are always more appropriate ways to say unappropriate things. In many cultures "I was in the toilet" may seem somewhat crude or manner-lacking, so you could use widely used synonyms and  euphemisms.

Some  euphemisms I know of are

> I was heeding the call of nature
>
> I was in a private meeting
>
> I had to excuse myself
>
> I went to the bathroom
>
> I was washing my hands

The problem with these is that the other party has to know *exactly* what you mean in order to prevent trouble. Someone could misinterpret them deliberately and accuse you of lazing around. So saying "I was in the toilet" might be better than "I was washing my hands" in this particular situation.

As Mister Positive already stated, you should make sure someone is available if and when you expect a delivery, phone call, visitor or things like that. It's enough to tell them "Please stay here in case the delivery arrives. I have to be away for a few minutes." No need for more details.

Comment: Those are [*euphemisms*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euphemism), not synonyms.

Answer (score 13):

Telling the **truth** as you did was the right thing to do, lying serves no purpose.  In this case, I would *ignore the minor teasing* and put it out of your mind.

The next time something is to be delivered, be sure someone is watching for it *should you need to take a break* of any kind.  (Lunch, toilet, etc.)

Comment: Or, if there's no one else around, you can also put up a sign saying "Back in 5 minutes"

Comment: Euphemisms aren't lies, and it's often socially expected to use them (the same could be said about not oversharing). Although I don't see much of a problem with "in the toilet".

Comment: @Dukeling The truth usually suffices in a case like this.

Comment: yep, just ignore it or joke back 'yeah really I'm Batman and had to go out save some lives for a minute'